# dataframe drop rows based on specific conditions of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a part of df:

```
   NUMBER         MONEY
    12345           20
    12345          -20
    123456          10
    678910          7.6
    123457          3
    678910         -7.6
```

I want to drop rows which have the same NUMBER but opposite money.

The ideal outcome would like below:

```
   NUMBER         MONEY

    123456          10

    123457          3
```

Comment: Could there be more than 2 entries per group?

Comment: yes. In fact, these entries are not one-to-one correspondence (I mean the total amount is an odd number). For example, maybe there are three entries are [Number] 12345, two of them [Money] are 20, one [Money] is -20. I just want to delete two [Money] is the opposite, and keep one whose money is 20.

Answer (score 1):

If there are just 2 rows in a group, use:

```
df[df.groupby('NUMBER').MONEY.transform('sum').ne(0)]
```

---

```
   NUMBER  MONEY
2  123456   10.0
4  123457    3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> df[~df.assign(MONEY=df.MONEY.abs()).duplicated(keep=False)]
```

---

**Output:**

```
   NUMBER  MONEY
2  123456   10.0
4  123457    3.0
```

From comments(by @piRSquared):

By using assign, a new column was added to `df` and the subsequent `drop_duplicates` takes into account both `NUMBER` and the absolute value of `MONEY`

`df[~df.assign(MONEY=df.MONEY.abs()).duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: This also drops values with the same sign

Comment: by using `assign`, I add a new column to `df` and the subsequent `drop_duplicates` takes into account both `NUMBER` and the absolute value of `MONEY`... `df[~df.assign(MONEY=df.MONEY.abs()).duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: @piRSquared I will add your comment as answer. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @piRSquared yes agree not worth spending the required time for these cases